# Apply aspect to all methods/actions in a class

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-5, postsharp

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5, I want to log all exceptions that occurs in the controller's actions.

To accomplish this I'm creating a custom aspect using PostSharp (in a dll), there I've already created the code to write the log files, now I want that the aspect can be controller-wide (do not want to apply it by hand to all methods).

The aspect's code looks like this:

```
using System;
using PostSharp.Aspects;

namespace Banlinea.Ceb.Domain.Aspects
{
    public class LogException : OnExceptionAspect
    {
        public LogException()
        {
            ApplyToStateMachine = true;
        }

        public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            //Code for logging the exception

            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.ThrowException;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I want in my controller is to do something like this:

```
[LogException]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Other()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Another()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Just decorate the class, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this byimplementing IAspectProvider

http://doc.postsharp.net/iaspectprovider

```
public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement) 
{ 
    Type type = (Type)targetElement; 

    return type.GetMethods().Select( 
       m => return new AspectInstance(targetElement, new LogException()) ); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply PostSharp aspects across your codebase by using a feature called [attribute multicasting](http://doc.postsharp.net/attribute-multicasting).

For example, when you apply a method-level aspect on a class level or assembly level, then it is automatically copied to all the methods in the corresponding class or assembly. You can additionally filter the target elements by setting the attribute properties, such as [AttributeTargetTypes](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattribute_attributetargettypes), [AttributeTargetMemberAttributes](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattribute_attributetargetmemberattributes) etc.

The sample code from your question should actually work as you expect.